# Remove column from data frame if all values in the column are identical

Tags: r, dataframe

What would be the most efficient way of removing a column from a data frame if it had all of the same value?

Here is an example df, but my df is over 10^8 columns, so I am looking for the most efficient way possible:

```
df <- data.frame(c(0, 0, 0, 0, 1), c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0), c(1, 1, 1, 0, 1), c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1))
```

In this example, columns 2 and 4 should be removed.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

One `diff` based solution could be as:

```
df[,apply(df,2,function(x)!all(diff(x)==0))]

#    c.0..0..0..0..1. c.1..1..1..0..1.
# 1                0                1
# 2                0                1
# 3                0                1
# 4                0                0
# 5                1                1
```

Answer (score 0):

A `plyr` solution:

```
library(plyr)
df <- df[,colwise(function(x) length(unique(x)))(df)>1]
```

Answer (score 0):

We can use the `select_if` function from the [dplyr](/questions/tagged/dplyr) package with a user-defined function to check if the unique values are two or more in each column.

```
library(dplyr)

# Define a function to check if two or more values in a vector
not_unique <- function(vec) length(unique(vec)) > 1

# Use select_if to select the column
df2 <- df %>% select_if(not_unique)

df2
#   c.0..0..0..0..1. c.1..1..1..0..1.
# 1                0                1
# 2                0                1
# 3                0                1
# 4                0                0
# 5                1                1
```

We can also use `sapply` from the base R.

```
df[, sapply(df, not_unique)]
#   c.0..0..0..0..1. c.1..1..1..0..1.
# 1                0                1
# 2                0                1
# 3                0                1
# 4                0                0
# 5                1                1
```